# Write oracle DB view based on different column time stamp difference

Tags: sql, oracle, view

I am trying to write a view where one of the column is a business logic which is like a SLA time difference based on received message state.

Example is below.. where for same MSG_GUID, we have different PAYLOAD_TYPE which represent the different state of message and created time shows the time it was inserted in DB.

PayloadType=1 will always be in DB for all message but
here I will have either Payload_type =2 or 3 for same message GUID but not both at same time

```
MSG_GUID             PAYLOAD_TYPE       CREATED_TIME                  
------------------------------------- ------------ ----
5dd222f2175e14       1                   02-MAY-14 04:22:11                       
5dd222f2175e14       2                   02-MAY-14 04:28:11                      
5dd222f2175e14       3                   02-MAY-14
```

or

```
MSG_GUID             PAYLOAD_TYPE       CREATED_TIME                  
------------------------------------- ------------ ----
5dd222f2175e14       1                   02-MAY-14 04:22:11                       
5dd222f2175e14       2                   02-MAY-14                       
5dd222f2175e14       3                   02-MAY-14 04:28:11
```

now, In my view I have to display **SLATime which would be time difference of Payload_type 1 and 2 or 1 and 3.**  .. here messageGUID will remain same for this... same way I will have 100's of record.

Could someone please tell me how I can write SQL query to achieve this .

Expected Result --

If Payload_type 1 and 2 available for same MSG_GUID then

```
SLATime
-----------
0 HOURS 6 MINUTES 0 SECS (created time difference of Payload_type 1 and 2 row)
```

but if Payload_type 1 and 3 available for same MSG_GUID then

```
SLATime
-----------
0 HOURS 6 MINUTES 0 SECS (created time difference of Payload_type 1 and 3 row)
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the results that you want.  I do not fully understand what you want to do.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Updated expected result.

Comment: Could someone pls suggest me possible solution here..

Answer (score 0):

If you want the difference with the `created_time` that has no time component, then you want logic like this:

```
select msg_guid,
       (max(case when payload_type = 1 then created_time end) -
        (case when max(case when payload_type = 2 then created_time end) <>
                   trunc(max(case when payload_type = 2 then created_time end))
              then max(case when payload_type = 2 then created_time end) 
              when max(case when payload_type = 3 then created_time end) <>
                   trunc(max(case when payload_type = 3 then created_time end))
              then max(case when payload_type = 3 then created_time end) 
        end)
        ) as diff              
from table t
group by msg_guid;
```

This returns the result as fractions of a day.

Comment: I am getting error like this when I run your query by adding my DB table name in place of t -- ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 5 Column: 80

Comment: @kumarb . . . You should put your table name in place of `table`, like `from YOURTABLENAME t`.

Comment: I am getting same error even after using my table name as suggested by you.. I have also checked table column names also..

Comment: Hello, Thanks its working for me now... but when I have my datatype as DATE then its displaying results as expected but when I use datatype as TIMESTAMP this query fails and giving me error like "ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND"

Comment: @kumarb - this query works with timestamps (though I think the subtraction is the wrong way around, if payload one is the earliest time); but it gets an `interval` result, so it's what you're doing to it next that is throwing that error. Mostly for Gordon's benefit, [there's a follow-up question about this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23511511/266304).