# How to write oracle sql query to get day and time from difference?

Tags: oracle

I have two columns with timestamp

```
   created                                updated
27-Jan-22 5.30.50.490000000 AM  28-Jan-22 02.51.25.27005700 AM
```

When I do (created-updated) in select query I get `+00 21:20:34.780057`

How can I update my query to get only the day and time that is till seconds not even + symbol?

Is there any SQL function to do data ?

My Orcale sql query is

```
Select (created-updated) as Past from user_info;
```

Comment: As what data type - a string? If so, maybe [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23512364/266304)? But is there a limit on the number of days? If it was always <= 31 then you could use date manipulation; I suspect that might not apply here though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `REGEXP_REPLACE`:

```sql
SELECT updated - created,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(
         updated - created,
         '^((-)|\+)0*(\d+ \d\d:\d\d:\d\d)(\.\d*)?$',
         '\2\3'
       ) AS past
FROM   table_name
```

Which matches:

- `^` from the start of the string;
- `((-)|\+)` match either `-` or `+` and, if it is `-` then capture it in the second capturing group;
- `0*` match zero-or-more zeroes (leading zeroes before the number of days);
- `(\d+ \d\d:\d\d:\d\d)` matches one-or-more digits (days), a space, 2 digits (hours), colon, 2 digits (minutes), colon and 2 digits (seconds) as the third capturing group;
- `(\.\d*)?` optionally, match `.` followed by zero-or-more-digits (the fractional seconds) as the fourth capturing group;
- `$` finally match the end-of-the-string.

And then replaces the match with `\2\3` which is the contents of the second and third capturing group and corresponds to whether the interval is negative and the day-to-second components.

Effectively, it will strip the leading `+` and any leading zeroes on the days and the trailing fractional seconds.

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (created, updated) AS
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2022-01-27 05:30:50.49', TIMESTAMP '2022-01-28 02:51:25.270057' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2022-01-24 00:00:00.00', TIMESTAMP '2022-01-28 02:51:25.270057' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2022-01-30 00:00:00.00', TIMESTAMP '2022-01-28 02:51:25.270057' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | UPDATED-CREATED | PAST |
> | --- | --- |
> | +000000000 21:20:34.780057000 | 0 21:20:34 |
> | +000000004 02:51:25.270057000 | 4 02:51:25 |
> | -000000001 21:08:34.729943000 | -1 21:08:34 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=cffb15bfd3301f2dfdbf78e42ba1d284)*

Comment: Thankyou @MT0 can u explain what regex is doing i am pretty bad in regular expression. I am learning thses days